# Worksheet Change event VBA code and it crashes excel 2013

Tags: vba

I have opened a new question after people have helped me figure out how to get my first problem fixed, now I have a new problem.  You will find the coding on the "INITIATING DEVICES" page below.  The idea for the second to last part of the code was to add columns (text values) from B7:b and E7:E and display it on column J7:J.  So if Photo is entered into B and Pass is entered into column E then the result will be Photopass in column J.  The original code works fine if run via the macro command.  The problem is that I tried to add it into some of my existing code and now the whole entire program will crash when information is entered into ANY cell.  The program becomes unresponsive and then it shuts down and starts up again.  I don't get a code or Debug message.  Here is the entire code on the page.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 7 And UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then
    Sheets("MESSAGE CHANGES").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, 3) = Sheets("INITIATING DEVICES").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 3).Value
    Application.Goto Sheets("MESSAGE CHANGES").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 3)

End If


 If Target.Column = 6 And UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then
    Sheets("DEVICE NOTES").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, 3) = Sheets("INITIATING DEVICES").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 3).Value
    Application.Goto Sheets("DEVICE NOTES").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 3)

End If


 '(replace if new code fails)If Target.Column = 5 And UCase(Target.Value) = "FAIL" Or Target.Column = 5 And UCase(Target.Value) = "DAMAGED" Then
    '(replace if new codes fails)Sheets("FAILED DEVICES").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, 3) = Sheets("INITIATING DEVICES").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 3).Value
 If Target.Column = 5 And UCase(Target.Value) = "FAIL" Or UCase(Target.Value) = "DAMAGED" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("FAILED DEVICES").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, 5) = Sheets("INITIATING DEVICES").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 5).Value
    Sheets("FAILED DEVICES").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 5) = Sheets("INITIATING DEVICES").Cells(Target.Row, 11).Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True


End If
'code that will place date/time when value is selcted in E
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then
   Range("I" & Target.Row).Value = Now

End If

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("INITIATING DEVICES")

lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("J7:J" & lastRow).Value = Evaluate("=B7:B" & lastRow & "&E7:E" & lastRow)


End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
With Sheets("INITIATING DEVICES")
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range("A1:H" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Address
End With

End Sub
```

Thank you for any help that you can give me, if you need anymore information I can send the inspection file and also offer more information if needed.  I'm sure I messed something up and that's why it keeps crashing.  Still learning here.

Answer (score 0):

IF it is crashing then the `Change` event is being called repeatedly. You need to use

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

at an appropriate point to prevent the Change event being triggered again, as you make changes (with your code) to the worksheet.

Comment: Alternatively, consider whether you need to use the Change event at all, perhaps having a button on the worksheet to run your code.

Comment: Can you explain a little more.  The Original code was to simply use it as a button that would run a macro.  It would work fine but getting the user/inspector to run the macro was a pain so I was trying to make it run by itself, like a lot of the other things on the page.  The idea that once column "E" had an answer that the results of "b" and "e" would be displayed on "J".  The answers are calculated in real time on the "executive summary" page.  It counts the total of the text value words and displays them on that page.  If a result is removed it is subtracted etc. Where would the code go?